# html break in php for button

Tags: php, html, button, break

I want a button to show up if an if statement in php is true. To my knowledge you can't use html in php, so how do i do it?

This is the code:

```
<!-- begin of form -->
<form method="post" action="something.php">
<input type="text" name="something" required="required" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
$something = $_POST["something"];
if($something == "blabla")
{echo"yes blabla";}

//this is where i would like to have a button
<form method="link" action="someurl.com">
 <input type="submit" value="Go">
 </form>
// end button
  } ?>
<!-- end of form -->
```

Tried to do it this way. leave a gap in the php code, and catch the last accolade from the if isset construction in a separate php part, but now it takes the if always for true.

```
<!-- begin of form -->
<form method="post" action="something.php">
<input type="text" name="something" required="required" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
$something = $_POST["something"];
if($something == "blabla")
{echo"yes blabla";}
?>
//this is where i would like to have a button
<form method="link" action="someurl.com">
 <input type="submit" value="Go">
 </form>
// end button
 <?php } ?>
<!-- end of form -->
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks is advance!
i've searched thouroughly, but couldn't find a similar question.
Please redirect me if there are similar qustions with answers.
PS sorry for my bad english, but i'm a dutchman..

Comment: Validating with integers is easier than strings... You should use strict cast type validations by using `===`

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- begin of form -->
<form method="post" action="something.php">
<input type="text" name="something" required="required" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
$something = $_POST["something"];
if($something == "blabla")
{echo"yes blabla";
?>
//this is where i would like to have a button
<form method="link" action="someurl.com">
 <input type="submit" value="Go">
 </form>
// end button
 <?php } ?>
<!-- end of form -->
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: There is no closing } after echo "yes blabla";
Therefore, if $something == "blabla", It will show the form button.

Comment: Nice spot, but your "answer" is an exact match to the OPS code from first glimpses. Add a chunk of text showing what you've done.

Answer (score 0):

You can output it by making a whole html block php-dependent:

```
$test = 1;
if ($test) { ?>
  <button>Good</button>
  <?php }
else { ?>
  <button>Bad</button>
  <?php }
```

Will output the button when the condition is 1. There's another method, however not normally recommended as it makes your code messier:

```
$test = 1;
if ($test)
  echo "<button>Good</button>";
else
  echo "<button>Bad</button>";
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly give a nice example on how to validate the post contents

Comment: What do you mean? You can put all of that inside another braces with another condition without problem, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch between HTML and PHP any time you want by opening `<?php` and closing `?>`

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $something = $_POST["something"];
        if($something == "blabla")
        {
            echo "yes blabla";

            ?>
                <form method="link" action="someurl.com">
                    <input type="submit" value="Go">
                </form>
            <?php

        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Indentation and alternative control statements can be prettier

```
<!-- begin of form -->
<form method="post" action="something.php">
<input type="text" name="something" required="required" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])):
        $something = $_POST["something"];
        if($something == "blabla"):?>
            yes blabla
        <?php endif;?>
        //this is where i would like to have a button
        <form method="link" action="someurl.com">
            <input type="submit" value="Go">
        </form>
        // end button
    <?php endif; ?>
<!-- end of form -->
```